# Problems uploading video files to a existing bucket with AWS on iOS

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the samples provided by Amazon to make an app to upload videos to the server (S3). The sample generates a bucket and stores an image there. In my case, I am using previously generated bucket to store the videos, but if I erase the bucket generation code the video upload stops in the way.
The generated bucket is not used to store the video. Also, if the bucket generation throws an exception (because the bucket already exists for example) the file upload still works.

I think there is another initialization I have to do before send the files.
Any ideas?

Here my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.s3 = nil;
    aws_bucketName = @"bucketname";     // this is not the real name
    aws_key = @"****  HIDDEN ********";
    aws_secretKey = @"****  HIDDEN ********";

    if(self.s3 == nil)
    {
        // Initial the S3 Client.
        self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:aws_key withSecretKey:aws_secretKey];
        self.s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_EAST_1];      // the bucket region is 'US Standard'

        //*******************************//
//        @try
//        {
//            // Create the picture bucket.
//            NSLog(@"Start with bucket generation");
//            S3CreateBucketRequest *createBucketRequest = [[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:aws_bucketName andRegion:[S3Region USStandard]];
//            
//            NSLog(@"Buquet requested, now response [bucket: %@]", aws_bucketName);
//            S3CreateBucketResponse *createBucketResponse = [self.s3 createBucket:createBucketRequest];
//            
//            NSLog(@"Bucket generated");
//            if(createBucketResponse.error != nil)
//            {
//                NSLog(@"Error: %@", createBucketResponse.error);
//            }
//        }
//        
//        @catch (NSException *exception)
//        {
//            NSLog(@"There was an exception when connecting to s3: %@",exception.description);
//        }
        //**********************************//
    }
}

- (IBAction)uploadFileButtonTouchUp:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Upload started");
    // Get file path
    NSString* fileName = @"upTest.mp4";
    NSString *fileDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *finalFilePath = [fileDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", fileName ];

    NSLog(@"The file to be uploaded is: %@", finalFilePath);
    // Call file upload
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalFilePath];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    [self uploadWithData2:videoData videoName:@"iosUploadTest.mp4" bucketName:aws_bucketName];
}


//*************************************************//
//*********     File upload              **********//
//*************************************************//
- (void)uploadWithData2:(NSData *)data videoName:(NSString *)videoName bucketName:(NSString*)bucketName
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        // Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
        S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:videoName
                                                                  inBucket:bucketName];
        por.contentType = @"movie/mov";
        por.data        = data;

        // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
        S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(putObjectResponse.error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", putObjectResponse.error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Video uploaded succesfuly");
            }

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
        });
    });
}
```

The bucket generation code is commented.

Comment: You can use the AWSS3TransferManager for uploading the video and other files. For more details visit this blog http://iosbucket.blogspot.in/2015/04/amazon-aws-s3-integration-in-ios-app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting content type to `video/mp4` just to mitigate possible unforeseen issues with MIME types.

I would also advise [reading this](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads), it contains some different methods for uploading, and dealing with threads as you do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the error you're encountering? You seem to be handling exceptions in the bucket initialization, but not in your upload code.  Are exceptions enabled in the SDK? You can read [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-span-class-matches-Exceptions-span-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS) for enabling/disabling exceptions in the AWS SDK for iOS.

If exceptions are in fact enabled, you'll need to add a `@try { } @catch ()` block to your upload code, which may allow you to catch the exception generated.

You can also turn on verbose logging in the SDK to see raw requests to the service by using `[AmazonLogger verboseLogging]`.  Including any errors in your post will better allow us to help you debug the issue further.